# Gnome Mail Icon from top bar shows number of unread email

Tags: mail

I'm very new to Ubuntu so please bear with me.  On the latest Ubuntu (12.04) I have set up thunderbird to read my Gmail account. I know there are browser addons that show you how many unread emails you have, but is there a way I can get this integrated with the Unity Mail icon on the top bar?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure why this is happening but can you please **try setting Thunderbird as the default mail client**.

> You can access this in **SETTINGS**, then click **DETAILS** (in SYSTEM
>   Section), then click on the **Default Applications** from the left
>   list and change **Mail** section to Thunderbird.
>
> Restart and check if it's working now.

Let me know if this worked as I don't have a sure answer but think it has something to do with default applications and would be nice to know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't work. Thunderbird was already set as default email client. I do get the on screen notification, but the mail icon remains the same

Comment: I found an add-on that is required for the menu integration through Mozilla's website, check this https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/messaging-menu-integration/ . You could **check if this add-on is present in Thunderbird and is enabled** before trying to install it from their site.

Comment: This addon is already installed.

Comment: Sorry this is all I know, I'll research it a bit and comment if I find anything

Comment: I know this might sound silly but can you click **Edit** > **Preferences** and in the **General** Tab check if it **Show in the Messaging Menu** is selected and **for messages in all folders**.

Comment: Yes, it is currently set to that.